# Как создать аннотацию логгер для ArrayList?

Tags: spring, aspectj

У меня есть несколько сервисов:

```
@Service
public class Order{...}

@Service
public class Statistic{...}

@Service
public class Product{...}
```

Все сервисы объединены в общем классе в ArrayLists

```
public class MyExample{

@MyLogAnnotation
private List<Order> listOrder;
@MyLogAnnotation
private List<Statistic> listStatistic;
@MyLogAnnotation
private List<Product> listProduct
}
```

Как сделать реализацию аннотации (@MyLogAnnotation)? Которая мониторит листы, и каждый раз, когда в лист добавляется новый сервис, в лог записывается время, количество сервисов и класс нового сервиса.

Comment: Поясни подробнее, что ты хочешь. Ибо с одной стороны `Order` у тебя объявлен как `@Service`, а с другой ты вроде как хочешь его использовать, как POJO.

Comment: Не правильно я изложил(. Вопрос такой,  нужно написать аннотацию на аспектах, которая мониторит лист объектов @MyLogAnnotation
private List<Objects> listProduct. Каждый раз когда в лист добавляются новые обекты, через метод add(). Аспект перехватывает это событие, считает количество элементов в листе, имя класса и печатает инфу в лог.